# Change Variable colors if else in scss

Tags: css, if-statement, sass, scss-mixins

I am trying to change color on click of change contrast (adding change-contrast class to body) in scss.

my **static** colors would be :

$primary-color-blue: **#2aace2**;

$mid-blue-color: **#2695d2**;

$dark-blue-color: **#124b62**;

---

on **change** contrast :

$primary-color-blue: **#177eab**;

$mid-blue-color: **#1c6f9b**;

$dark-blue-color: **#124b62**;

should be something like  in sass

```
if(change-contrast) {
//  console.log (get High Constrast Colors)
}
else {
//  console.log (Static Colors)
}
```

Iam trying to do like below, but if i do like below i have to add to each and every class.

```
@mixin branding {
  @each $brand in $brand_clr {
    &.#{nth($brand,1)} {
      $primary-color-blue: #177eab;
      @content;
    }
  }
}

test {
    background: $primary-color-blue;
    @include branding {
      background: $primary-color-blue;
    }
}
```

Appreciate your help on this !!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the solution comes across a well structured color map. You need to group colors by types (eg. static, contrasted). Then, use a mixin to avoid duplicating youself.

```
$colors:(
  standard: (
    primary-color-blue: #2aace2,
    mid-blue-color:#2695d2,
    dark-blue-color:#124b62
  ),
  contrasted: (
    primary-color-blue: #177eab,
    mid-blue-color:#1c6f9b,
    dark-blue-color:#124b62
  )
);


@function get-color($key, $type: 'standard'){
  @each $name, $color in map-get($colors, $type){
    @if($key == $name){
      @return $color
    }
  }
}

@mixin get-color($property,$color){
  #{$property}: get-color($color);
  @at-root body.contrasted & {
    #{$property}: get-color($color, contrasted);
  }
}


.className{
  @include get-color(background-color, primary-color-blue)
}
```

This will output:

```
.className {
  background-color: #2aace2;
}
body.contrasted .className {
  background-color: #177eab;
}
```

Comment: instead of changing in every class can we do it from variables ?

Comment: I mean if(standard) {
 primary-color-blue: #2aace2,
}
else { 
 primary-color-blue: #177eab,
}

if we can try like this, it will be time consuming. no need to add it to each and every class. but what u have provided is also good one :)'

Comment: You can use the function just like: `color: get-color($color, contrasted);` and don't use the mixin. But I think the code should complie into something...

Comment: i was thinking how would i add gradient color " background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(46, 173, 226, 1) 0%, rgba(129, 208, 217, 1) 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(46, 173, 226, 1) 0%, rgba(129, 208, 217, 1) 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(46, 173, 226, 1) 0%, rgba(129, 208, 217, 1) 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2eade2', endColorstr='#81d0d9', GradientType=1);"

any idea.. Thanks

Comment: and also do i  need to create new mixin for border, border-bottom: 1px solid #f00; ??

Comment: Gradient is a long property but still is, so add it in the colors map. I don’t know tour build process but using autoprefixer is easyer for vendor prefixing. For borders, I would suggest to separate properties like: border-bottom-color, border-bottom-width, border-bottom-style.

Comment: Hi.. I making use of text color and background color, now the client has came  up with having different background images for high contrast..
now in this case i have to keep 4 different images 2 for standard (normal & retina) and 2 for contrasted (normal & retina).. request you to give some inputs..

Comment: Maybe then you want to change the mixin name and I think you should just add `background-image` and `background-image-retina` in both standard and contrasted maps. Then use the mixin twice, one by default and the other in the retina @media query.